# Scrapy referring back to original page instead of next page

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I am having trouble using scapry to follow a "next page" link - according to the log it is referring back to itself instead of the "next page" url. Here is the code:

```
import scrapy

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "quotes2"
start_urls = [
        'http://search.jeffersondeeds.com/pdetail.php?instnum=2016230701&year=2016&db=0&cnum=20',
]

def parse(self, response):
    for quote in response.xpath('//div'):
        yield{
            'record' :  quote.select(".//span/text()").extract()
        }

    next_page = response.xpath('//*[@id="nextpage"]/a/@href').extract()

    if next_page is not None:
        print("GOOOO BUCKS!!")
        next_page = response.urljoin(next_page)
        yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)
    else:
        print("Ahhh fooey!")
```

The xpath looks to be correct:

[image]

But the url in being captured as next_page is the original url (starts_urls)

Comment: what's the output of the `print` you set?

Comment: It prints "GOOOO BUCKS!!". I added a print(next_page) and it prints the original URL (not the one in the link)

Comment: please debug your code, next_page isn't None, but it is an empty list, and I see the actual nextpage link being generated with a javascript inside `'//table//script/text()'`

Comment: Yes - that was it - javascript generated link. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

next_page isn't None, but it is an empty list.

Now the `nextpage` link being generated with a javascript inside `'//table//script/text()'`

you can get it with: `response.xpath('//table//script/text()').re_first("href=\\'(pdetail.*)\\'>")`